# Angular, filter and show one object of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter

I have a list of names that is connected to different objects in an array. I would like to, whenever you click one of the names, get the values and output them in another list respective to that that object. For right now I console.log the right values, but don't know how to output it:

```
<a href="#" id="name" ng-click="updateIndex($index);">{{ person.name }}</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.updateIndex = function(index) {
            console.log($scope.person[index]); //Logs the right values
        }
```

How can I output the values from the object which name is clicked to:

```
<div class="wrap" ng-repeat="per in person">

        <div class="box">
            {{ person.name }}
        </div>

        <div class="box">
           {{ person.age }}
        </div>

        <div class="box">
           {{ person.town }}
        </div>

        <div class="box">
           {{ person.country }}
        </div>

        <div class="box">
           {{ person.gender }}
        </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by `output the values from the object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign $scope.person[index] to another variable in the click function and output it in the template.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please, mark one of the answers as the correct one to let everyone know, that this topic is solved. Thanks. Also +1 is also a nice way to thank anybody who helped you get to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the variable in the variable an use it:

```
$scope.updateIndex = function(index) {
     $scope.currentPerson = $scope.person[index] 
}

<div class="wrap" ng-repeat="per in currentPerson">

    <div class="box">
        {{ person.name }}
    </div>

    <div class="box">
       {{ person.age }}
    </div>

    <div class="box">
       {{ person.town }}
    </div>

    <div class="box">
       {{ person.country }}
    </div>

    <div class="box">
       {{ person.gender }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!